# nltk english corpus and python count

Tags: python, nltk

Why when I import `from nltk.corpus import words` and try to count specific strings I get some duplicates? For example the word *skirt* gets two hits with `words.words().count("skirt")` (btw, `words.words().count("Skirt")`
has 0 hits). When getting the index of *skirt* and slice the list I don't see any duplicate entry. I had sorted the list first as a sanity check also.  The same applies also with *short* and possibly with some other strings inside `words.words()`.

I don't think this is a bug in nltk.

Here is how to reproduce:

```
from nltk.corpus import words
words.words().count("skirt")

2
```

Someone would expect 1 as an answer. Why would a dictionary -not a python dictionary- have a duplicate of the same entry?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @MattDMo, what you are asking is included in the OP. Also there are no errors associated with the OP, are you asking to write in a different way the OP maybe? Sample input is given (the string "skirt"), a minimal reproducible example is the one liner command provided in the OP, and there are no errors also.

Comment: when I said dictionary I didn't mean a python dictionary (the data structure) but the nlp concept of a dictionary.

Comment: It looks like two lists were concatenated. You can see that every word in the list `words.words()[:235886]` is unique. There are 850 more words in `words.words()` but only 6 unique words appear beyond `words.words()[235886]` and these are: `{'behaviour', 'box', 'colour', 'harbour', 'humour', 'near'}`.

Answer (score 1):

`type(words.words()` actually returns `<class 'list'>`, not dict, so it's perfectly possible to have duplicates. If you sort the list using `sorted()`, indices 187162 and 187163 are both `"skirt"`.

```
>>> words_sorted = sorted(words.words())
>>> words_sorted.count("skirt")
2
>>> words_sorted.index("skirt")
187162
>>> words_sorted[187162]
'skirt'
>>> words_sorted[187163]
'skirt'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however, it is clear that I refer to a list in the original post. After all count() can't be applied to a type dict in python the way the code snippets are posted. So yes I am aware in my OP that I treat a list python object. The question is why would this list, that represents an NLP dictionary, would contain a duplicate. Is there a reason for this duplication?

Comment: Ah, I was confusing dictionary and dictionary. I think for that answer you'd have to ask the NLTK team, or at least search through their issues.